# ContextAction MenuItem Icon not showing in iOS platform in Xamarin.Forms PCL based solution

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi i'm developing app using Xamarin.Forms PCL based solution.For my app i need Listview ViewCell Contextaction. I referred [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#context/) document to add the contextActions.When i ran it in android the icon is displaying.but in iOS it is not working.

**Xaml code**

```xml
 <ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Text="Edit" x:Name="MenuEdit" />
    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeleteMenu" Icon="dustbin.png" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
  </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

Please anyone give the solution or related sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked Xamarin support the same question few weeks ago.

Below is the answer I got:

---

iOS does not support icons in the context menus like Android. You can use something like this to support both platforms:

```
<MenuItem Icon="dustbin.png" Clicked="OnDeleteMenu" Text="Delete"/>
```

This will show the text on iOS and the Icon on Android.

If you would like to see this feature added to Xamarin.Forms, please add a new post to https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions.

Comment: Its not coming for me.
<MenuItem Text="Detail" Clicked="OnDetail" Icon="~/drawable/icon"></MenuItem>

Comment: I must say It's amazing that you add a comment to the question closed more than 3 years ago and really expect an answer :-)
It's much better to start a new topic.
But anyway, I think that your "Icon" parameter contains illegal path. Try to put just a name without the path if it's in the "drawable" folder inside your solution

Answer (score 1):

:D I found the solution for icon on iOS by using font. ex: Text="❤ Favorite"